# How can I promote ham.se on my personal website?

Tags: support

I have a relatively well-known [ham-related personal website](http://hamwaves.com).
I am currently modernising its design and would like to promote ham.stackexchange.com.

What is available to do so? Can I gain some reputation by doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer addresses only the “gain” part of the question.)

You cannot [gain reputation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) by promoting the site. However, if other people visit a question using the special URL you can get from the “share” button, then you can be awarded [the Announcer, Booster, or Publicist badges](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

Comment: I hope, once we complete our beta, there will also be some banner material available.

Comment: @on4aa typically there is at least some art resources available after graduation, but it will be a while before that happens.